# How to deal with this problem of abstract matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

**First question:**

Let `A` and `B` be n-order square matrices, and `r(X)` denote the rank of matrix `X` (`r(X,Y)` is the rank of the augmented matrix composed of `X` and `Y`), then which of the following relations is correct (the answer is `A`):

$$\begin{eqnarray}
&(A)&\;  r(A, A B) =  r(A) \qquad
&(B)&\;  r(A, B A)  =   r(A)  \\
&(C)&\;  r(A, B)  =   \max \{r(A), r(B)\} \qquad 
&(D)&\;  r(A, B)  =   r\left(A^{T} B^{T}\right) 
\end{eqnarray}$$

I use the following code to judge the a option, and I can't get the correct result:

```
$Assumptions = Element[A | B, Matrices[{d, d}, Reals]]
MatrixRank[A] === MatrixRank[Join[A, A.B, 2]]
```

I wonder if there is any good way to solve this problem.

**Second question:**

It is known that the second-order matrix `A` has two different eigenvalues. $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ are two linearly independent eigenvectors of `A` and satisfy the condition of $A^{2}\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}\right)=\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}$. Now I want to find the determinant value of matrix `A` (the answer is `-1`).

```
Assuming[Element[A, Matrices[{2, 2}, Reals]] && 
  Element[a1 | a2, Arrays[{2, 1}, Reals]], 
 Solve[A.a1 == k1.a1 && 
   A.a2 == k2.a2 && (A.A).(a1 + a2) == a1 + a2, {k1, k2}]]
```

But the above code cannot find the eigenvalues of matrix `A`, what should I do?

Comment: The second question would be better posed in Mathematica as: 
`Resolve[Exists[{A, a1, a2, k1, k2}, 
  Element[A, Matrices[{2, 2}, Reals]] && 
   Element[a1 | a2, Vectors[2, Reals]] && Element[k1 | k2, Reals], 
  A.a1 == k1.a1 && A.a2 == k2.a2 && (A.A).(a1 + a2) == a1 + a2]]` 
... but Mathematica will not handle these kinds of abstract problems in this way.

Comment: What does `r(A,AB)` actually mean?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `r(A,AB)` is the rank of the augmented matrix composed of `A` and `A.B`.